# I have an array of blasts and an array of zombies, how can I efficiently detect collisions?

Tags: libgdx, game-physics

I have an array of blasts, and an array of zombies, but I'm struggling to find a way to efficiently detect collisions and remove both the blasts and zombies that have collided. Any suggestions?

```
    Iterator<Rectangle> blastIter = blasts.iterator();

    while(blastIter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle blast = blastIter.next();
        blast.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        if(blast.x + 16 > 800) blastIter.remove();
    }

    Iterator<Rectangle> zombieIter = zombies.iterator();

    while(zombieIter.hasNext()) {
        Rectangle zombie = zombieIter.next();
        zombie.x -= 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        //if(zombie.overlaps(blast)) zombieIter.remove();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the other iterator inside of the other iterator, try this:

```
Iterator<Rectangle> zombieIter = zombies.iterator();

while(zombieIter.hasNext()) {

    Rectangle zombie = zombieIter.next();
    zombie.x -= 150 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    Iterator<Rectangle> blastIter = blasts.iterator();

    while(blastIter.hasNext()) {

        Rectangle blast = blastIter.next();
        blast.x += 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

        if(blast.x + 16 > 800) blastIter.remove();
        if(zombie.overlaps(blast)) zombieIter.remove();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using something quite similar to this. The only things I did differently were declaring `Iterator<Rectangle> blastIter` outside the loop, but initializing it inside the loop, and moving the blast.x increment out of the loop as well, or else if there are multiple blasts, the speed of the blasts would get faster and faster :)

Answer (score 1):

Make nested loops, just like you have there, but one inside other (which is inside which is not important), so you'll have all combinations of objecst from those 2 lists.